# openAM - Active Directoy - won't authorize unless displayName equals sAMAccountName

Tags: active-directory, openam

We have added a realm in openAM that uses ActiveDirectory, and created a policy that allows access to a page if they are in a specific group. This works fine if the displayName is equal to the sAMAccountName, they can be authenticated and see the page. If the displayName is different from sAMAccountName, in the same group, they can be authenticated, but get a 403 error when they are forwarded to the page. Same behaviour if we add the users specifically to the subject, instead of the group. Anyone have an idea of what setting could be causing this? Any tips of where to look would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

This is quite difficult to tell without knowing more details (like OpenAM version). Are you using OpenAM identity subject as subject for the policy? If yes then it's most likely related to data store configuration. You need to enable 'message' level debugging and have a look into OpenAM debug log file. There has been an issue where OpenAM did not correctly build the 'uuid', the id OpenAM uses for its identity subjects.